# what does sqlsrv_query return for ALTER INDEX all ON tbl REORGANIZE query and why does sqlsrv_num_rows return FALSE?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv, codeigniter-4

I've created a pull request to add a `Database\ResultInterface::getNumRows()` function to CodeIgniter 4. Some [changes](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/pull/4049) I've made have broken a unit test. Specifically, an SQLSRV table optimization test is barfing because this framework tries to fetch a result array from the SQLSRV response to this table optimization query:

```sql
ALTER INDEX all ON db_job REORGANIZE
```

It's also a bit tricky to trace all the code being called that leads to this, but here's an exception:

```
1) CodeIgniter\Database\Live\DbUtilsTest::testUtilsOptimizeDatabase
CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException: Error retrieving row count

/home/runner/work/CodeIgniter4/CodeIgniter4/system/Database/SQLSRV/Result.php:198
/home/runner/work/CodeIgniter4/CodeIgniter4/system/Database/BaseResult.php:193
/home/runner/work/CodeIgniter4/CodeIgniter4/system/Database/BaseUtils.php:177
/home/runner/work/CodeIgniter4/CodeIgniter4/tests/system/Database/Live/DbUtilsTest.php:105
```

Dissecting that, we see that the [DBUtilsTest line 105](https://github.com/sneakyimp/CodeIgniter4/blob/num-rows-signed/tests/system/Database/Live/DbUtilsTest.php#L105) calls the [BaseUtils::optimizeTable](https://github.com/sneakyimp/CodeIgniter4/blob/num-rows-signed/system/Database/BaseUtils.php#L126) function with a table name, "db_job", and that uses the `SQLSRV\Utils::optimizeTable` var to construct the query I provided above. This sql is then fed to a db object that calls `CodeIgniter\Database\SQLSRV\Connection::query()` which, through inheritance and various function calls routes that SQL through `BaseConnection::query()` which feeds the sql to `BaseConnection::simpleQuery` which hands the sql to `SQLSRV\Connection::execute` which finally feeds the sql to `sqlsrv_query` and returns the result of that function back up through the call stack. So I guess this brings me to my first question:

**Question 1: What is the value of `$stmt` if this ALTER command a) succeeds or b) fails?**:

```php
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connID, 'ALTER INDEX all ON db_job REORGANIZE');
```

According to the [sqlsrv_query documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php), this function:

> Returns a statement resource on success and false if an error occurred.

Whatever that value is gets returned back up the call stack to line 625 of `BaseConnection::query` where, if successful, it is stored as `$this->resultID` and fed as the second parameter to the constructor at line 676 which effectively returns `new SQLSRV\Result($this->connID, $this->resultID)`. To be clear, connID refers to the SQLSRV db connection and resultID refers to whatever value of `$stmt` was returned by the sqlsrv_query call above.

The resulting `$query` variable is an instance of system\Database\SQLSRV\Result in this function:

```php
    public function optimizeTable(string $tableName)
    {
        if ($this->optimizeTable === false)
        {
            if ($this->db->DBDebug)
            {
                throw new DatabaseException('Unsupported feature of the database platform you are using.');
            }
            return false;
        }

        $query = $this->db->query(sprintf($this->optimizeTable, $this->db->escapeIdentifiers($tableName)));
        if ($query !== false)
        {
            $query = $query->getResultArray();
            return current($query);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

An instance of SQLSRV\Result will not be false so that code will attempt to call `SQLSRV\Result::getResultArray` which through inheritance calls `BaseResult::getResultArray`. This seems wrong to try to getResultArray from a query that optimizes a table or any sort of ALTER query, however an MySQL server will return a series of records in response to an OPTIMIZE query. Also, the sqlsrv_query function we just ran is just returning some of sqlserver statement or resource as its result.

I guess this brings me to my second question:
**Question 2: How does one tell from the `$stmt` result of sqlsrv_query whether the ALTER statement above succeeded?**

Curiously, none of these pecularities caused any problem before. The problem appears to have arisen because I've deprecated an unused BaseResult::numRows property that was never being set in the [old getResultArray code](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/Database/BaseResult.php#L190) and have replaced it and all references to it with a new getNumRows method. In my new [BaseResult::getResultArray function](https://github.com/sneakyimp/CodeIgniter4/blob/num-rows-signed/system/Database/BaseResult.php#L183) we now check getNumRows instead of numRows. This works fine for MySQLi, SQLite3, and PostGreSQL, but barfs in SQLSRV because the aforementioned `$stmt` result of the `sqlsrv_query` ALTER statement gets fed to `sqlsrv_num_rows` and returns `false`, which signifies an error according to the docs. Here's the code for `SQLSRV\Result::getNumRows` function:

```php
    public function getNumRows() : int
    {
        // $this->resultID contains the sqlsrv_query result of our ALTER statement
        // and $retval comes up false
        $retval = sqlsrv_num_rows($this->resultID); 
        if ($retval === false)
        {
            throw new DatabaseException('Error retrieving row count');
        }
        return intval($retval);
    }
```

This brings me to:
**Question 3: would it ever make any sense to try and fetch results from or call sqlsrv_num_rows on the result of an ALTER INDEX query?**

Comment: I don't have any specific advice on how to help you move forward, but db frameworks I've worked with usually have some sort of "execute non-query" functionality that allow you to run commands that are not intended to produce a result set. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 for example. Does CodeIgniter have a similar concept?

Comment: You need to set `scrollable` property of the `CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver` instance to one of `SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET`, `SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC` or `SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED`. Function `sqlsrv_num_rows requires a client-side, static, or keyset cursor, and will return false if you use a forward cursor or a dynamic cursor. (A forward cursor is the default.). I think, that this is the explanation for the unexpected behaviour in your code.